# run a screen after reboot

Tags: linux, cron, gnu-screen

i tried to google but had no luck perhaps because i am not sure on the terms to look for. basically im trying to auto run a screen after the system reboots. i tried crontab but it seems that i cannot execute the jar file unless im in the directory.

something like
`crontab -e`:

```
@reboot screen -d -m -S ModBot java -jar /home/themoduser/modbotfiles/ModBot.jar  start
```

im not sure if that is a correct method or if trying to use a .sh script:

```
cd /home/themoduser/modbotfiles/
screen -d -m -S ts3bot java -jar ModBot.jar
```

and in crontab

```
@reboot /home/themoduser/modbotfiles/ModBot_startscript.sh start
```

Comment: You can do `cd /somewhere && screen --etc` to `cd` before running `screen`, but making a script file is preferable.

Comment: how would the script file look like?

Comment: Basically just like you posted it. Just add a `#!/bin/sh` and chmod +x the file.

Comment: Make sure the command works outside of crontab first, then go through [the crontab info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)  to troubleshoot it in crontab.

Comment: Once you make sure it works without crontab, you can temporarily create a crontab entry that runs the command just once (say, 34 13 * * * screen ...` to run it at 1:34pm), so you don't have to reboot the system to test it.

Comment: the .sh script method works when i run it manually but does not run on startup with crontab